# Runtime PINMUX control on Mediatek MT7628 + Linux-5.4.154

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, gpio, hardware

I have a Mediatek MT7628-based microcontroller (Onion Omega2+).  I would like to disable some peripherals and use the pins as regular GPIO.  I've been trying to modify the devicetree, with only modest success (and long development cycle time, since I have to keep recompiling the kernel).

It appears that recent kernels may be able to control the PINMUX through sysfs files (maybe `/sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl`?)  If this is possible on 5.4.154 (OpenWrt 21.0.2), what is a recipe for disabling UART2 and using the Tx and Rx pins (GPIO20, 21) as standard GPIO?  How about SPI (GPIO14-17)?

Comment: No, it's not possible in older kernels and quite limited (to some drivers and hence hardware) in the current one.

Comment: Aw, that's too bad.  I guess I'll have to go back to fiddling with device tree overlays.  Hopefully I'll be able to find enough examples in a flexible machine like a BeagleBone.  Thanks!

Comment: I think that the current kernel interface was exactly developed for BB in mind.